# Можно ли протестировать в java зажата кнопка или нет?

Tags: java, javafx

Можно ли протестировать в java зажата кнопка или нет, например если я зажму кнопку W, то k=1, а если отожму то k=0?
Если можно пример.
Вот код моей кнопки:

```
if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("W")) {
                k = 1;
            }

                switch (k) {
            case 1:// W
                gc.drawImage(fon, 0, 0, 1280, 720);

                koy = koy - SPEED;
                gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                gc.fillOval(kox - 5, koy - 5, kord + 10, kord + 10);

                gc.setFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN);
                gc.fillOval(kox, koy, kord, kord);
                for (int l = 0; l < 26; l++) {
                    if (koy == prom1[l] - kord) {
                        koy = koy + 720 + kord;
                    }
                }
                break;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можно. Ловите ваш ивент на Scene,Layout-e:

setOnKeyPressed() - При ножатии кнопки.

setOnKeyReleased() - При отжатии кнопки.

А пишите это как то вот так:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.W){
            //do_something
        }

scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.W){
            //do_something
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод [setOnKeyPressed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnKeyPressed-javafx.event.EventHandler-).

В данном случае будет что-то типо такого:

```
node.setOnKeyPressed(ke - > {
    switch (ke.getCode()) {
    case KeyCode.W:
        gc.drawImage(fon, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
        koy = koy - SPEED;
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fillOval(kox - 5, koy - 5, kord + 10, kord + 10);
        gc.setFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN);
        gc.fillOval(kox, koy, kord, kord);
        for (int l = 0; l < 26; l++) {
            if (koy == prom1[l] - kord) {
                koy = koy + 720 + kord;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
});
```